# how to fix exports is not defined error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gruntjs, babeljs

I used to uglify and hash my js files. Then I wanted to rewrite my js file using [es6](/questions/tagged/es6).

I only started with two files, `search.js` and `select.js`, (amongst dozens) that depend on each other.

My  run the [es6](/questions/tagged/es6) conversion and then the uglify task.

[grunt](/questions/tagged/grunt) runs without errors.

When I try my website, in the browser console I see this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

`search.js` contains the [es6](/questions/tagged/es6) `export` statement and `select.js` contains the `export` statement as well and the `import` to import exported `search.js`

How do I fix this given that I'm using [grunt](/questions/tagged/grunt) and all my js files are aggregated into one final uglified file?

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33294807/1507546), it gives great answers on what's going on but it does not suggests any grunt solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294705/gulp-babel-exports-is-not-defined

Comment: @Tuko90 that explains well why this error came up, but no solution for grunt users