# Export is not defined

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: `exports` is not defined

It seems like this question has been asked and answered several times. This is an example of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined) being asked.

The only problem I'm having is that I can't find the **tsconfig.ts** file people keep mentioning in their answers. There's no such file in VS solution.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition.

## EDIT

I define all the common types in a file called CommonTypes.ts

```
class ddlData {
    ctrId: string;
    id: string;
}

interface ISelectedIdsObj {
    facilityId: number;
    AllCk: boolean;
    AllSelected: boolean;
    Ids: number[];
    totalItems: number;
}

//More classes and intefaces here...

export { ddlData, ISelectedIdsObj, IPaginationData, IHeaderColumn, ISelectedListItem }
```

This is how I call it

```
/// <reference path="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

//import { ddlData, ISelectedIdsObj, IPaginationData, IHeaderColumn, ISelectedListItem } from '../Commons/CommonTypes'
```

I'm getting the `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at line 3`.

## EDIT 2

I've created 2 typescript files: `test1` and `test2`.

This is test2:

```
export const x = 1;
```

and this is test1:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

import { x } from './Test2'

$(function () {
   alert(x);
});
```

I'm still getting the same error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at Test1.js:3`

Comment: Who ever is trying to close the question and down voted me because it's not clear. I'm trying to import a series of classes using ` import { class1, class2, ...} from '../path'`. I'm getting the error I posted above. I've done some researches and found some answers. But I don't know whether those solutions applied to Visual Studio. If you don't understand my question why not explain why you find difficult instead of wanting to close the question?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: Do you have `tsconfig.*json*` in your solution? If yes, can you add the contents to question?

Comment: There's no such file in the solution. That's why I asked the question. Because it seems like tsconfig.*json* can be found in VS Code not in VS.

Comment: You can add it by using *Add new item* but it doesn't matter. Can you try removing this line `export { ddlData, ISelectedIdsObj, IPaginationData, IHeaderColumn, ISelectedListItem }` and adding `export` to each individual entity as mentioned in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html?

Comment: No luck. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: It is likely there are some other errors in your files. Try to do the simplest `export const x = 1` in one file and `import { x } from './thatfile'` in another and see what you get

Comment: instead of `//More classes and intefaces here...` can you put actual code? If you are still getting error after declaring each entity separately as `export` that means there is some error in the rest of the code or some other file.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad, those classes and interfaces where in the same file as the one containing all the functions. And it was working fine. All I did was copy/paste them to another file then comment out in the first file.

Comment: @unional, please see the second edit.Now that I'm researching on the error, I've started to suspect that it is related with some javascript loader: something like `Requirejs` and `CommonJs`.

Comment: @Richard77 sorry for delay. Just quick question, are you getting this error in browser? Is this error occurring in client side code or server side code?

Comment: by the way, tsconfig.json is just a file that you create at the root of your project.

Comment: @unional, I'm getting the error in the browser. In visual, everything is just fine. I'm getting even the intellisense. It's when I run the application, nothing is happening. When I press F12, I see the error.

Comment: Can you post your compiled `Test1.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have clarified that the issue is occurring in browser, it is easy to fix. 
As you don't have created `tsconfig.json` file in your solution, your project is compiled with default configuration in VS. i.e. it will use `CommonJS` for as target module. More info about `tsconfig.json` can be read [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

This is the actual reason behind the error. Web browsers don't support CommonJS by default. The same issue will occur with `require(...)` also. You will need to use either module loaders such as `RequireJS` or `amd` or you can use packaging tools such as [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/) which does this for you. `Webpack` is easy to configure and diverse packaging tool that has gained lot of popularity.

See [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294705/gulp-babel-exports-is-not-defined) answer