# How to use webpack with typescript?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm using the example from cycle.js

MyScript.ts

```
import { run } from '@cycle/run';
import {makeDOMDriver, div, button} from '@cycle/dom';
import _ from 'lodash';
import xs from 'xstream';


function main (sources) {

  console.log('Hello World');

  const add$ = sources.DOM
    .select('.add')
    .events('click')
    .map(ev => 1);

  const count$ = add$.fold((total, change) => total + change, 0);

  return {
    DOM: count$.map(count =>
      div('.counter', [
        'Count: ' + count,
        button('.add', 'Add')
      ])
    )
  };
}

const drivers = {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver('.app')
}


run(main, drivers);
```

When I compile my project, it creates MyScripts.js

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var run_1 = require("@cycle/run");
var dom_1 = require("@cycle/dom");

function main(sources) {
    console.log('Hello World');
    var add$ = sources.DOM
        .select('.add')
        .events('click')
        .map(function (ev) { return 1; });
    var count$ = add$.fold(function (total, change) { return total + change; }, 0);
    return {
        DOM: count$.map(function (count) {
            return dom_1.div('.counter', [
                'Count: ' + count,
                dom_1.button('.add', 'Add')
            ]);
        })
    };
}
var drivers = {
    DOM: dom_1.makeDOMDriver('.app')
};
run_1.run(main, drivers);
//# sourceMappingURL=MyScript.js.map
```

When I inspect the page in chrome I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

MyScript.js line 2

This answer says I probably need webpack.
[gulp babel, exports is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294705/gulp-babel-exports-is-not-defined)

How do I load webpack?  Is it like `<script type='javascript' src='webpack' >`

Comment: Webpack is a build tool that compiles your Javascript code into browser ready (web packed) code. Browsers don't (and shouldn't) know how to handle import statements. imports/exports are just for organizing your source code. You don't require webpack, you run it over your code as an external tool. Suggested reading: http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using systemjs as my module loader which requires the correct tson.config as well as the correct mappings in the system.configjs.js file

WebPack is an alternative module loader

Answer (score 2):

After months of problem with getting a basic TypeScript environment setup I finally got it working yesterday, mainly by copying this starter project.

https://github.com/krasimir/webpack-library-starter

I was reluctant to use Webpack since it is a heavy dependency that install a lot of other **npm** packages, but replicating the starter project was pretty easy and after that everything worked pretty well.